# Is it possible to compare 2 contents of same line in .txt file using linux?

Tags: linux

Let's say I have the following content in text file

```
input.txt
aaa bbb
ccc ddd
```

I would like to compare user input with the content in text file.

Let's say user is prompted to enter 2 strings, if first string matches the content in text file **(let's say aaa, which is the first content of line 1)**, how should I modify my code to make the program to compare the second string that user entered with the second content **(bbb)** on the same line?

```
echo "First input: "; read input1
echo "Second input: "; read input2
if [ "$input1" = $(< input.txt) ]; then
 # content matches
else
 # content doesn't match
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Read the first line from `input.txt`:

```
read -r shouldbe_input1 shouldbe_input2 < <(head -n1 input.txt)
```

Then just compare:

```
if [ "$input1" = "$shouldbe_input1" ] && [ "$input2" = "$shouldbe_input2" ]; then
       echo yay
else
       echo not yay
```

fi